# What is the name of CImg's library?

Tags: c++, cimg

I'm trying to find the Cimg library so that I can add it to libraries I have in Dev-c++, but there's no folder in Cimg named lib, so what's it called? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to switch to an IDE which has evolved past the stone age. Dev-C++ was terrible 4 years ago, and since then it hasn't been updated or supported *at all*. It is dead, and starting to smell. There are many *free* alternatives that are worth using. Switch to one of them.

Answer (score 3):

[Follow the CImg tutorial](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__tutorial.html), which describes how to use it. Also check out [their FAQ](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__faq.html#ssf22):

> 2.2 How to use CImg in my own C++ program ?
>
> Basically, you need to add these two lines in your C++ source code, in order to be able to work with CImg images :

```
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
```

CImg is a [header-only library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only) so you build it with your source, no external libraries to link.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old now, you may have found a solution.
But in case someone else needs help, here is my contribution:

I think you'r trying to read jpeg files with Cimg. Jpeg support is not built in Cimg, you'll need an additional lib (libjpeg or imageMagick).

In case of libjpeg you'll have to add 
    #define cimg_use_jpeg
before including CImg.h and you'll need libjpeg.lib
This page may help you : [Compile LibJPEG](http://w3studi.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/~bischowg/languages/C++/CPPlibjpeg.html)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about [this](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/index.shtml), it appears to be header-only.

Just `#include "CImg.h"` and you're good to go, no (extra) library files needed.